# Delete property from Neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to delete some node properties from my graph. Following the cypher guidelines I have tried the following:

```
START n=node(1)
DELETE n.property
RETURN n
```

I get an error message:

```
Expression `Property` yielded `true`. Don't know how to delete that.
```

I can replicate this on console.neo4j.org. How are you supposed to delete the property of a node?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What version of Neo4j are you using? Since Neo4j 2.0 (I'm not sure what milestone exactly, tried it with M03), properties are not "deleted" anymore but "removed":

```
START n=node(1)
REMOVE n.property
RETURN n
```

Should work with Neo4j 2.x.

This is also reflected in the documentation. On the right side of the page (perhaps after some loading time) you have a pull-down menu for choosing your Neo4j version. When you go to the DELETE documentation and choose the 2.0.0-M03 milestone, you will notice that the "Delete a property" menu point disappears (link to the M03 documentation on DELETE: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/query-delete.html).

Instead, the documentation for 2.0.0-M03 on REMOVE (here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/query-remove.html) does now list the "Remove a property" section.

Answer (score 13):

Just another example.

For **Neo4j 3.0**, given a node with property keys, name and age, to delete the age property is also valid:

Create the node:

```
CREATE (n {name:'Andres', age:25}) return n
```

**Delete the property key age:**

```
MATCH (andres { name: 'Andres' }) REMOVE andres.age RETURN andres
```

From Neo4j 3.0 documentation https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-remove

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove relationship property out of multiple relationships between the nodes.

```
MATCH (a:Application {name:'A'})-[r:REQUEST_TO]-(d:Application {name:'B'})
WHERE ID(r) = 684
REMOVE r.property
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is:

> *to delete some node properties from my graph*

If your node type is "Thing", and you want to remove a property called "size", you can remove that property from all of the nodes with this:

```
MATCH (t:Thing)
REMOVE t.size
```